# The Toolbar shows only the Title from the Item in menu_main for toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar, android-menu

The Toolbar shows only the Title from the Item in menu_main for toolbar

My MainActivity Toolbar

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/MyToolbar"
    app:theme="@style/Theme.Mytheme"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    />
```

menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/coins_value_item"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/coin_bar"
        android:title="OnlyThisTitleShownOnPhone"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

coin_bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:paddingVertical="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_round_corner"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/coin_icon"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/coins_value_text_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:fontFamily="@font/main_font"
    android:text="1000" />

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Correctly shown in Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio Image Correctly Shown]

What's wrong in that situation?

Incorrectly displayed only on the device, namely, only the title property of the item itself is displayed

Comment: What is correctly shown in Android Studio?

Comment: @quantumPuter custom view in toolbar

Comment: Hi Dominik. Can you please attach a device screenshot so that we can see the difference between the Android Studio and Device Version? Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I just changing this:

```
android:actionLayout="@layout/coin_bar"
```

to this:

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/coin_bar"
```

Comment: I failed to notice any differences.

Comment: For anyone trying to utilise this answer, I believe Dominik probably changed it to: app:actionLayout="@layout/coin_bar"